# Filtering in haystack does not work

Tags: django, search-engine, django-haystack

I have a model which has a field status definde as:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.CharField(_('entry status'), default=ENTRY_DRAFT, max_length=2, choices=ENTRY_CHOICES)
```

Right now I use haystack with simple engine set. My search index is below:

```
class EntryIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = CharField(model_attr='owner')
    date_published = DateTimeField(model_attr='date_published')
    status = CharField(model_attr='status')

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Entry.objects.all().distinct()

site.register(Entry, EntryIndex)
```

The problem is that when I try to filter my entries using 
`entries.filter(status=ENTRY_DRAFT)`
I receive all objects not only matching to filtering. Entries is SearchQuerySet passed to other function. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Thanks for remind me to answer this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred only when I used dummy search engine. The solution was to change search engine to other.